# Слитно или раздельно в предложении слово "непроданный"?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Как учитывается товар, непроданный до указанной даты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раздельно.

Подставим глагол:
*Как учитывается товар, что был непроданным до указанной даты?* || Плохо подходит. Здесь качество — был вот таким.
*Как учитывается товар, что не был проданным до указанной даты?* || Подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Раздельно. В "**непроданный** товар" выделенное болдом слово - прилагательное, а в "не **проданный** *до указанной даты* товар" выделенное им - причастие, поскольку имеются выделенные курсивом зависимые слова, а прилагательному зависимые слова не положены. Причастие - как бы глагольная форма, поэтому "не", относящееся к причастию, пишется отдельно.

Comment: Изредка прилагательные могут быть и с зависящими словами. В данном случае зависимые слова не указывают на 100%, что это причастие.